# Forcing all errors to show in Xcode

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, runtime

Is there a way in Xcode to show all errors, regardless of #. I am missing something in my code that is now causing 50+ errors, but not all errors show up. The multiple errors are likely being caused by a syntax error on a page, but because not all errors are showing I have no idea which one likely failed.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Xcode stops after some errors by default.

You need to select option "Continue building after errors" option under 
Xcode >> Preferences >> General

[image: step1]

[image: step2]

Comment: This makes no difference in Xcode 10. It still stops short of showing all errors.

Comment: 10 years later, and still valid response 

Answer (score 0):

Go to the error highest up in the file.  That's usually where syntax errors start and then snowball.  It will be slightly before that error.

Answer (score -1):

I was missing my @end in my .h file. And it was closer to the top of the list of errors as Tim mentioned.